# PHP fopen failed to open stream: Permission denied between 2 accounts in cpanel

Tags: php, cpanel

I have a VPS with 2 CPanel accounts and I need to write a file from account1 to account2 and I have the following error:

> **Warning: fopen(/home/account2/public_html/files/file.csv) [function.fopen]**: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/account1/public_html/test.php **on line 7**

**My code:**

```
$content = array('sku','status','visibility');
$fp_mt = fopen("/home/account2/public_html/files/file.csv", 'w');
fputcsv($fp_mt, $content);
fclose($fp_mt);
```

Someone have an idea  what I need to do?

Thanks

Comment: go into the files directory and run into the terminal `sudo chmod 777 file.csv`

Comment: The file doesn't exist when the php run, every file will have different name

Comment: Even the parent directory have permissions 777

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/264383/how-to-set-file-permissions-so-that-new-files-inherit-same-permissions

Comment: If you are using suphp, you will have to add both users in the same group in httpd.conf also you will have to exclude openbasedir restriction if it is enabled...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP - Failed to open stream : No such file or directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/php-failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory)